# Copy multiple cells VBA not working

Tags: vba

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("A2) Monthly P&L (Source)").Activate
Range("AR400,BR400").Copy
```

Trying to copy a value from those 2 cells, but what ends up happening is it copies the cell in AR400 and then the cell to to the right of it as well, not BR400.

Comment: Sorry, but probably your English is not your native. Please, try as much as you can decribe your issue. What do you want to copy and where to?

Comment: I want to copy values from cells AR400 & BR400 which is in Workbook A into Workbook B. I have the code that paste values into workbook b working properly. Like I said when I run that code it works with no errors but it copies the value from AR400 & the column next to it, not BR400. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Starting from your code, I think you can do `.Copy` twice:

```
Range("AR400").Copy
' ...pasting...
Range("BR400").Copy
' ...pasting...
```

However, `Worksheet.Activate`, `.Copy`, `Worksheet.Activate` another sheet, supposedly `.Select`, `.Paste` is usually not good. *Activating* (or *selecting*) sheets and *selecting* cells is really discouraging when you write a coded procedure. No advantages - that's slower to execute and more to write.

**Option 2**

Much faster and recommended option if you want to copy/paste values:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("A2) Monthly P&L (Source)").Range("AR400")
```

This way the cell A1 in "Sheet2" would instantly get the value from cell AR400 in Sheet "A2) Monthly P&L (Source)".

<sub>Again, you would need to use it twice to paste another Range ("BR400").</sub>